# Stopping a Thread the Java way

Tags: java, multithreading

After looking through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html), I'm trying to stop a thread, here's what I have

```
Thread restartLocation = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread mThis = Thread.currentThread();
                while(restartLocation == mThis) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        Log.d("Delay", i+" seconds");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
});

//When the map is drag stop it update with the users location
//If the user drags the map to look around they dont want it moving back
mf.setOnDragListener(new TouchableWrapper.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrag(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
        Log.d("Map", "Stopped location and remove drag listener");
        if (motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            //Stop restartLocation if it's running
            restartLocation.start();
        }
    }
});
```

However, I get an error on this line `while(restartLocation == mThis) {` variable restartLocation might not have been initialized. How can I fix this error? Or, is there a better way I can stop this Thread?

Comment: While you are creating `restartLocation` object, you are trying to use it, thus compiler is throwing uninitialized error.

Comment: Why do you think calling `restartLocation.start()` would stop the restartLocation thread? Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: I don't, the comment `//Stop restartLocation if it's running` is a placeholder for the stop code I eventually find.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `restartLocation` reference within its initialization itself. It's not yet been initialized. You can't use it untill it is initialized. that's why the error!

Comment: Your answer is correct as far as what the compiler is able to prove.  But maybe the reason Tom Hart is confused is, he knows that that run method will not actually be called until after the assignment has been done.  That's because he knows something the compiler does not know.  He knows how the Thread class behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Make `restartLocation` a member variable. Since members are initialised with a default value (null in that case), the error should dissapear.

Of course this is just a suggestion since you don´t gave any info about the environment your code is running in.

However, your code contains another error:
Variables outside the scope of an anonymous class must be declared `final` in order to be accessable from within the anonymous class. In your code, you won´t be able to read `restartLocation` since it was not declared `final`.